# QGIS not showing spatialite's timestamp values in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I opened in QGIS (3.14.16) spatialite's table which has `timestamp` type field, but values in this field are not visible (NULL) in Attribute Table.

[image: Table structure]

In DB Manager view these values are visible.

[image: DB Manager - Preview]

but in Attribute Table they are NULL.

[image: Attribute Table]

[image: Layer Fields]

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: Times in SQLite and SpatiaLite are complicated because SQLite saves dates and times as strings (timestamp type is just a hint) https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html. Your rimes seem to be ISO time strings and there is probably some way to handle them. I would try to convert SpatiaLite db into GeoPackage with GDAL because GeoPackage has better defined rules for handling the time strings. Or I would try to find some way for changing the exposed field type into string.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, I'd report it at https://www.github.com/qgis/qgis/issues

Comment: @bugmenot123 thanks! reported https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39929 and It'll be available in the next 3.16.1 release (in ~1 week) ;)

Comment: Excellent, thank you too! Best close the question then if that is possible :)